# eclipse che starting error

Tags: eclipse, docker, ubuntu-16.04, eclipse-che

I installed the eclipse `che` in my ubuntu machine using docker, after installed it worked fine. Then I restart the computer and try to run it using `che start` command then it give an error like this

```
ERROR: !!!
ERROR:      A container running ECLIPSE CHE named "che-server" already exists.
             1. Use "info" to find it's URL.
             2. Use "restart" to stop it and start anew.
             3. Stop it with "stop".
             4. Remove it manually (docker rm -f che-server) and try again. Or:
             5. Set CHE_SERVER_CONTAINER_NAME to a different value and try again.
ERROR: !!!
```

According to the message I type the `docker rm -f che-server` then `che` ran and all my workspaces have been lost. How do I overcome this ?

Comment: Have you simply tried `docker start che-server` ? That may do the trick, restarting the stoped container.

Comment: Yeah it worked... thanks for the instructions. Could explain why the server need to start? I'm new for the docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest alternative where you will not loose your workspaces,
You can start the che server in different container by just passing docker with argument CHE_SERVER_CONTAINER_NAME=che-server-new, see below example:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e CHE_SERVER_CONTAINER_NAME=che-server-new codenvy/che-launcher:nightly start
```

*For Fixing Existing Problem:*
If you want to run a same container then you can kill the existing container and try to start it.

```
docker kill che-server
```